# LibGdx Setting Velocity

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

How can I set Linear Velocity in only X direction without effecting the motion of Y Direction to a body in LIBGDX Box2D. I applied an impulse to the body to make it jump now I want to move it towards right or left I tried applying the following method:

```
setLinearVelocity(Vector2)
```

But it is stopping the vertical motion. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just retrieve the current velocity via the getter, manipulate it and set the new one.

```
Vector2 velocity = body.getLinearVelocity().cpy();
velocity.set(500, velocity.y);
body.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
```

Comment: do you even need to set it? Should be the same object so a set after the manipulation shouldn't be needed right? I mean if you just get the velocity and manipulate it. No need for a copy or stuff like that. You would save some operations i think.

Comment: @BennX I think it is needed because on some platforms the getter and setter calls native C++ code. Manipulating the vector alone should not be enough and you need to call the setter again. I'm not sure about the cpy(). It might be possible that the returned vector is just a temp and it can be changed, but to be save I added the cpy().